# No such module '####'

Tags: swift, xcode, import

I am new to Swift/xcode and stumped by the Import.

[image]

However, it does seem to be picking up the file.  Notice "AnimationType" on the last line.  This is an enum defined in FoldingCell.  See below what happens if I comment out the import.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you open the workspace and not the project?

Comment: Doubled checked that -- it is the project

Comment: @jz_ You know that you are supposed to open the workspace and *not* the project? Did you install your pods? Please explain how you are managing the library.

Comment: In all previous tutorials, etc. I have opened .xcodeproj.  So I am at a loss at to what you mean.

I am not managing through pods.  Only through xcode on my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try cleaning the project and building it again.
2. Click your project name. In the right side, scroll down to "Linked Frameworks & Libraries". On that section, theres a "+" button, click it. You will be shown a list of frameworks. You will find your "FoldingCell" framework probably at the top. Add it. Then clean and build the project.